# How to save custom snippets to existing ace snippet file

Tags: angular, code-snippets, ace-editor

We have developed an application for editing code snippets available in the ace editor for each mode. We are using ng2-ace-editor in angular 6. Snippet file for each language mode is saved inside the ace library. we need to edit each snippet and user must be able to save his snippets into the same file. We have accomplished editing the snippet and registered the newly added snippet, thus the user can add the newly added snippet on the editor real-time. But when the page is reloaded it will be lost. We need to save the snippet to the file already exist in the ace library, as this is saved in a different format with some "\n tab" characters. The snippet is available for editing after it is parsed using SnippetManager. But we couldn't find any documentation to make it to the old format with our newly added snippets.

```
//snippet manager is included for managing snippets
var snippetManager =  ace.acequire('ace/snippets').snippetManager;
// getting existing snippet array (free from special characters, \n etc)
var m = snippetManager.files[this.editor._editor.session.$mode.$id];
m.snippetText = this.snippettext;
// unregister already esisting snippets
snippetManager.unregister(m.snippets);
m.snippets = snippetManager.parseSnippetFile(m.snippetText, m.scope);
// register newly added snippets along with old snippets
snippetManager.register(m.snippets,'tex');
```

After this, I need to save these registered snippets to the existing file with the asking format.

Comment: why do you want to save in the same file? save into new file, and use it instead of the old one if it exists.